# Java boolean equals method with ArrayLists

Tags: java, arraylist, equals

I have a Class named `Produto` and a Class named `Fatura`, the last one have a `private long nif` and a `private ArrayList<Produto> lista = new ArrayList<Produto>();`

On my `equals()` method I have:

```
public boolean equals (Object o) {
    if (o != null && this.getClass() == o.getClass()) {
        Fatura f = (Fatura) o;
        return (this.nif == f.nif && f.lista.equals(o));
    }
    return false;
}
```

On my `Main_test` I create three `Produto`s. Then I create two `Fatura`s. I add the `Produto`s to the `ArrayList` and I set `fatura1` to `fatura2`:

```
fatura1 = fatura2;
```

I then call the `equals()` method to see if `fatura1` equals `fatura2` but it returns `false` I don't know why. It should return `true` because they are the same, they have the same `nif` and the same `ArrayList`.

Thanks

Comment: What about the class Produto? How do you call the equals method? You need to give more detail.

Comment: The class Produto have a code,name and price.
And I add the Produto on Fatura List (ArrayList)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the problem is here:

```
f.lista.equals(o)
```

You are not passing the right argument to `equals`. Do this:

```
f.lista.equals(this.lista)
```

Comment: It returns true but if I have the same nif but different list it returns true too.

Comment: Pass `this.lista`

Answer (score 0):

Your result is false because **lista** is an **ArrayList** Object while your **o** is an **Object**. You need to extract your alist into an object like **Futura**

Here's a sample:

You should write this:

```
return (this.nif == f.nif && f.lista.get(0).equals(o));
```

Instead of this:

```
return (this.nif == f.nif && f.lista.equals(o));
```

You're comparing an ArrayList to an Object class, which caused you to get "false" as your result.

Comment: Don't work, I have this error:
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Index: 0, Size: 0